# visiting $n$ distinct sites in a random walk of $n$ steps on $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request, random-walk

Consider the symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. I am looking for references about the number of ways to visit $n$ distinct sites in $n$ steps where I don't count the origin, so visiting $n+1$ distinct sites in $n$ steps is not possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: [OEIS A001411](https://oeis.org/A001411) might be worth reading

Comment: @Henry ; Thanks.

Comment: It seems I once drew a [picture to illustrate this](https://oeis.org/A001411/a001411.gif)